# three.js json loadingmanager model not displayed

Tags: json, three.js

I want to preload all models and textures with a loadingbar in my project. For that i use the LoadingManger from three.js but i have problems with preloading the json Models. They load but i am unable to display them. Here is an [example](http://www.never-mage.de/webgl/jsonmodel.html).

You can see in the console that 200 Meshs are created. 100 For the Asteroids and 100 for the Ships.

Withoud the LoadingManger i can display the models (asteroids) so there should be no problem with the model. You can see in the example Asteroids that are loaded without the loading manager.

Here my simplified code for the problem

```
$(function(){
        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var debugScene = true;
        var controler, camera, controls, scene, renderer;
        var objectControls;
        var ship1geometry,ship1material;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //LOADMANGER
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
        manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
            $('#loader').css({width:(Math.round(loaded / total *100))+"%"});
            console.log( item, loaded, total );
        };
        manager.onLoad = function () {
            $('#loaderholder').fadeOut(function(){
                init();
                animate();
            });
            console.log('all items loaded');
        };
        manager.onError = function () {
            console.log('there has been an error');
        };

        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(manager); // init the loader util
        loader.load('models/shiptest.json', function (ship1geometry) {
            var ship1material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();
        }, "models");

        function init() {
            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 1, 10000000 );
            camera.position.x = 0;
            camera.position.y = 0;
            camera.position.z = 1500;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor("black");
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.autoClear = false;

            var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.enableDamping = true;
            controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
            controls.enableZoom = false;
            controls.minDistance  = 50;
            controls.maxDistance  = 300000;
            controls.autoRotate = false;
            controls.autoRotateSpeed = 0.05;

            controls.target.x = 0;
            controls.target.y = 0;
            controls.target.z = 0;

            light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x666666 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 10000 );
            light.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );

            var params = { recursive: true };
            objectControls = new ObjectControls( camera, params );

            shipCount = 100;
            for (var p = 0; p < shipCount; p++) {
              var pX = Math.random() * 5000 - 2500;
              var pZ = Math.random() * 5000 - 2500;
              var ship = createShipMesh(pX,0,pZ,0,0,0,ship1geometry,ship1material);
              scene.add(ship);
            }

            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            loader.load('models/asteroid.json', function (geometry, mat) {
                var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( mat );
                asteroidCount = 100;
                for (var p = 0; p < asteroidCount; p++) {
                      var pX = Math.random() * 5000 - 2500;
                      var pZ = Math.random() * 5000 - 2500;
                      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
                      mesh.rotation.y = -Math.PI/Math.random();
                      mesh.position.set( pX, 0, pZ );
                      scene.add(mesh);
                }
            }, "textures");

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            if(debugScene){
                var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 900000, 10000 );
                gridHelper.setColors( 0x0000ff, 0x808080 );
                scene.add( gridHelper );
                var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper( 500 );
                scene.add( axisHelper );
                console.log(scene);
            }
        }
        function onWindowResize() {

            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;

            camera.aspect = width / height;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        var lastTimeMsec= null;
        var nowMsec= null;
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
            update();
        }
        function update(){
            controls.update();
            objectControls.update();
        }

        function render() {
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        function createShipMesh(positionX,positionY,positionZ,centerX,centerY,centerZ,geometry,material){
            positionX = centerX + positionX;
            positionY = centerY + positionY;
            positionZ = centerZ + positionZ;
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
            mesh.rotation.y = -Math.PI/Math.random();
            mesh.position.set( positionX, positionY, positionZ );

            objectControls.add( mesh );
            mesh.select = function(){
                controls.target.x = position.x;
                controls.target.y = position.y;
                controls.target.z = position.z;
                controls.dollyIn(2);
                controls.minDistance  = 20;
            }
            return mesh;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the problem on my own. the Loading Manager works with json but my mistake was to set the variable ship1geometry global and was thinking that the loader would overwrite this variable so that i can use it later in the scene. That was wrong. I just needed to assign the response from the loader in my globaly set variable. So here is the right code

```
var ship1geometry,ship1material
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
    $('#loader').css({width:(Math.round(loaded / total *100))+"%"});
    console.log( item, loaded, total );
};
manager.onLoad = function () {
    $('#loaderholder').fadeOut(function(){
        init();
        animate();
    });
    console.log('all items loaded');
};
manager.onError = function () {
    console.log('there has been an error');
};

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(manager); // init the loader util
loader.load('models/shiptest.json', function (geometry,mat) {
    ship1geometry = geometry;
    ship1material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map:mat });
}, "textures");
function init(){
     ...
}
```